# Populating the form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a little form with php and javascript. It's a simple form with radio buttons and a couple of text boxes. Under the form there's a table , which is showing the values from the DB. 
[image]

The php is taking the values of the text boxes and radio buttons and creating a special URL, which is the "Forwarder" in the picture below.

Now when I press the "Edit" button in the table, it must populate the current record with the values of text boxes and radio buttons into the form, so I can edit the values, creating another URL and update the record. The problem is, I don't know how to do it. There can be many records in the table. I don't know how to populate the form with the current record values. And I can't create a table in the DB for each of the values either. 
Please can anybody give me some advice ? I will be very thankful.
Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

On edit click you can run a select query based on the ID of the record. I see you are displaying it, so just grab the text of the ID field from the table. And we assume you have already saved the data from the form above...

Comment: First of all thanks for answering. After adding the record, the php is generating a special URL , with the values taken from the form above. I need that values, not the values from the table.

Comment: For example, there's a URL like this,

https://somewebpage.com/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline&IACcustid=***VALUE1***&wctx=wa%3Dwsignin1%***VALUE2***3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fiamcloud%252Esharepoint%252Ecom%252F

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: I was thinking of using a regexp for taking out the values from the URL. But I'm still searching another way for doing that.

Comment: Ok, so you are not using parameters, you are using a string with a specific delimiter. In that case you can use explode [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) which will return an array of strings.

Comment: Thanks , it helped me, I was thinking about regexp, but I forgot about the `explode` method. I will try to do that way now. Thanks again. I guess there's no other cleverer way.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a page that gathers the information, and input fields to the table. I'm not sure if fields are static or not, but just populate all the fields manually.

Then have form set to GET type and on submit will be sent by url to the handler page where you could have Query String with PHP so for example index.php?title=TITLE&field1=VALUE

then use $_GET['title] and $_GET['field1'] to grab the information, grab them fields and save back to database.